# Does power dissipate on real conductor when charge move from charged object to neutral charged object?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, electric-circuits

for example we have charged sphere and we have neutral charged sphere 
After we connect them with real conductor (few Ohm resistance) some charge will move from charged sphere to neutral sphere.

Will that moving charge be affected by Joule law on conductor? 
Why it will be/not be affected by dissipation on conductor resistance?

I read on internet that those charges aren't affected because current loop isn't closed. Is this correct?

Thank you,
Matija

Answer (score 0):

As soon as electrons move power will be dissipated. In your specific case, it will be dissipated in the resistor connecting the spheres and, to a very small amount, due to electron movement in the spheres itself.

The only exception would be superconductors.